# Center div vertically to its sibling div

Tags: html, css

I have two sibling divs and a containing div.

Current situation is this:
[image: Example]

I want the two inner divs to be centered vertically in respect to the outer div.
Notice that the outer divs has a changing size which is determined by the inner red div's size (which can change) and I think that's what makes this challenging. To me anyway...

The example displayed here is from [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/boluka/1/edit?html,css,output). Best solution is to modify it to work.

IE9+

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `vertical-align` css rule

```
#side {
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle; /* added this */
  background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png");
  background-size: contain;    
}

#sizey {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle; /* added this */
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

### [**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/kikigiyajeye/1/edit)

Comment: best answer cause I don't have to add margin

Answer (score 0):

Well if the outer div expands around the red one, you just need to center bart simpsons:

http://jsbin.com/foniduvolazo/1/

```
#outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#side {
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png");
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LuyIf)

`vertical-align: middle;` for `#side` and `#sizey`